# Tratando JSON no C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

Tenho um retorno de uma requisição HTTP no formato JSON. Ele vem da seguinte forma:

```
{
   "message": "authenticate"
}
```

É um retorno simples, mas sou iniciante em C# e gostaria de saber como faço pra atribuir somente a string "authenticate" em uma variável. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Esse é o json completo que você recebe?

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar a classe `JsonConvert` do [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). A instalação pode ser feita diretamente pelo Visual Studio como pacote NuGet. Basta executar o seguinte no Package Manager:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Para deserializar sua string JSON de uma forma prática e mais rápida, pode utilizar uma lista de pares de chaves e valores, faça como:

```
var jsonString = GetJson();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
```

Pode acessar o valor desejado dessa forma:

```
obj["message"];
// retorna a string "authenticate"
```

Outra forma é fazendo de forma mais tipada, criando o modelo do seu JSON em forma de um objeto estruturado, como:

```
public class MeuTipo {
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Assim pode deserializar seu JSON dessa forma:

```
var jsonString = GetJson();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MeuTipo>(jsonString);
```

E acessar assim:

```
obj.message;
// retorna a string "authenticate"
```

- [Código fonte do Json.NET no GitHub](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)
- [Documentação do Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

Answer (score 0):

O Nuget **Newtonsoft.JSON** é uma boa solução para este tipo de situações.

Você pode criar uma classe e deserializar o retorno:

Crie um pequeno exemplo:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZYGhBn